# Are these kinds of sentences correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Today when I was thinking these sentences came to my mind. I want to know whether these are gramatically correct or not.

1. The mechanic can make it be of no use.
2. John can make this book be like an encyclopedia.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use **make** meaning "force someone (to do something)". In the active voice, we use it with an infinitive without *to*. Building your sentences, you are trying to use "make" like that. However, the verb you are using after "make" is the verb *to be*. In this case just omit *be* altogether:

> The mechanic can make it of use / The mechanic can make it no use.
>
> John can make this book an encyclopedia. *(I don't see the reason why you must use "like" here)*

But if the verb after "make" were not the verb *to be*, you'd have to use it. For example:

> The boss made me *work* an extra day.
>
> The song makes me *cry*.

Comment: Thank you very much ... Do you mean using be in my sentences like that makes it look bad?

Comment: @user8718165 it's just not correct.